# How can you force Entity Framework to use string instead of char for CHAR, NCHAR, VARCHAR(1) and NVARCHAR(1) columns?

Tags: .net, sql-server, linq

We have a database table that currently has a `VARCHAR(1)` column.

We occasionally make changes to this table which require us to regenerate the object in the DBML file.  Our corresponding code wants to refer to this value as a string, but LINQ-to-SQL always assumes that it is a nullable char.  In order to get around this, we have to manually set the column to be a string in the DBML designer.  I'd like to prevent our developers from accidentally using char instead of string for these types of fields.

Is there a way to force Entity Framework to assume string for all `CHAR/NCHAR/VARCHAR(1)/NVARCHAR(1)` fields?

If there is not a way to do this, we'll probably change the column to be `VARCHAR(2)` or something like that.  Whatever we decide, we will propagate to several tables, as multiple tables are using this type of column definition.  The sheer number of columns that we would have to alter is what is preventing us from implementing this across the board at this time.

**EDIT:** Changed "Entity Framework" to "LINQ-to-SQL"

Comment: Is this in EF 4 or 4.1? Database first, Code first?

Comment: `VARCHAR(1)` is pointless - you have **two bytes** overhead on top of your actual string, so you're using 2-3 bytes here - to potentially store a single character (or not). For anything shorter than e.g. 5 or 10 characters, use `CHAR(x)` instead - much more efficient!

Comment: I don't understand "to prevent our developers from accidentally using char instead of string for these types of fields." - these fields are, by their definition, only capable of storing a single char. Why is it wrong for the developers to be aware of this, as opposed to them seeing something that can store a string, but they have to know to only put one character in it?

Comment: @marc @Damien neither `CHAR(1)` nor `char` can store **the empty string** - `VARCHAR(1)` and `string` can!

Comment: You are using term DBML (linq-to-sql) and Entity framework which have nothing to do with DBML so you should start by clarifying which technology are you using. Entity framework doesn't use `char` type.

Comment: @marc_s - I agree that VARCHAR(1) is pointless.  I have already discussed this with my colleagues, and they have agreed that these types of columns will not be created in the future.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka - We're just using LINQ-to-sql, not EF.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - I'm interested in more than just forcing char -> string.  For example, BIGINT fields are mapped to long, but we may have a coding convention to use Int64.  Is there a way to default columns to various types when dragging tables into the designer?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I solved it by using the POCO T4 templates and modifying the template to emit an additional property that makes some checks before setting the original property. The T4 template could identify the fields that require this by using a naming convention. Here's a link to my blog where I describe in a little more detail how this works http://nigelfindlater.blogspot.com/2010/04/implementation-of-custom-types-within.html

I guess an alternative approach could be to create a partial class that adds the additional property in a similar way.

I hope this helps...